# Use JavaScript to get value of the for each

Tags: javascript

I'm new using JavaScript. I need to get the value ${prdcts.precioUnidad} of the checked line. The idea is to set the total price in a dynamic way, so when the user checks or unchecks each line the value of total either adds the new value when checked, or subtracts the previous value when unchecked.

I tried to get the value using the getElement() methods, but I don't know how to access the value of the variable within that specific row.

This is the HTML:

```
<html><head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Ventas</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <center><h1>Venta de Productos</h1>
       <form action="venta.htm" method="post">
           <table id="tableID" border="4">
               <tbody><tr>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Nombre</th>
                   <th>Valor</th>
                   <th>Comprado</th>
               </tr>

                   <tr>
                       <td>2</td>
                       <td>Chupetin</td>
                       <td>5.0</td>
                       <td><input name="check" type="checkbox" value="2" label="2" path="prdcts"></td>                               
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                       <td>3</td>
                       <td>Alfajor DDL</td>
                       <td>30.0</td>
                       <td><input name="check" type="checkbox" value="3" label="3" path="prdcts"></td>                               
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                       <td>4</td>
                       <td>Sanguche Mila</td>
                       <td>60.0</td>
                       <td><input name="check" type="checkbox" value="4" label="4" path="prdcts"></td>                               
                   </tr>

           </tbody></table>
           <br>
           <br>
           <br>
           <table border="4">
               <tbody><tr>
                   <td>Total Compra: <input name="total" id="total" type="number" readonly="" value="0"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Monto Pagado: <input name="monto" id="monto" type="number" value="0"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Vuelto: <input name="vuelto" id="vuelto" type="number" readonly="" value="0"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input name="begin" onclick="calcularVuelto()" type="button" value="Calcular Vuelto"></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody></table>
           <br>
           <br>
           <input name="clear" onclick="window.location.href = 'venta.htm'" type="button" value="Borrar venta">
           <input name="begin" onclick="window.location.href = 'principal.htm'" type="button" value="Inicio">
           <input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirmar Venta">
           <br>
       </form>     
   </center>    


<script>

// Make it an Array with "Array.from" so we can use reduce() on it
   var $$checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=check]')),
           $total = document.getElementById('total');

// For each checkbox
   $$checkboxes.forEach(function ($checkbox) {
       // When its value changes, update total
       $checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
   });




   function updateTotal() {
       // For each checkbox
       alert("aca");
       var total = $$checkboxes.reduce(function (sum, $checkbox) {
           // If it's checked
           alert("aca2")
           if ($checkbox.checked) {
               var price = $checkbox.parentNode.parentNode // parent <tr>
                       .querySelectorAll('td')[2].innerText.trim(); // remove spaces

               // Add price to the sum
               return sum + parseFloat(price);
           } else {
               // If it's not checked, just return the current sum
               return sum;
           }
       }, 0);
       $total.value = total.toFixed(2); // Always 2 decimals
   }

   function calcularVuelto() {

       var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
       var pago = document.getElementById("monto").value;
       var fTotal = parseFloat(total);
       var fPago = parseFloat(pago);
       totalResta = fPago - fTotal;
       document.getElementById("vuelto").value = totalResta;
   }
</script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate the total:

```js
// Make it an Array with "[].slice.call" so we can use reduce() on it
var $$checkboxes = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=check]')),
    $total       = document.getElementById('total');

// For each checkbox
$$checkboxes.forEach(function ($checkbox) {
  // When its value changes, update total
  $checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
});

function updateTotal() {
  // For each checkbox
  var total = $$checkboxes.reduce(function (sum, $checkbox) {
    // If it's checked
    if ($checkbox.checked) {
      var price = $checkbox.parentNode.parentNode // parent <tr>
                           .querySelectorAll('td')[2].innerText.trim(); // remove spaces
                       
      // Add price to the sum
      return sum + parseFloat(price);
    } else {
      // If it's not checked, just return the current sum
      return sum;
    }
  }, 0);
  $total.value = total.toFixed(2); // Always 2 decimals
}
```

```html
<table border="4">
  <tr><th>ID</th> <th>Nombre</th> <th>Valor</th> <th>Comprado</th> </tr>
  <tr><td>x</td><td>X</td><td>5.99</td><td><input name="check" type="checkbox" value="x" label="X"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td>y</td><td>Y</td><td>3.95</td><td><input name="check" type="checkbox" value="y" label="Y"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td>z</td><td>Z</td><td>14.20</td><td><input name="check" type="checkbox" value="z" label="Z"/></td></tr>
</table>
<p>Total Compra: <input name="total" id="total" type="number" value="0" readonly/></p>
```

Comment: Hello @blex this is what i have in mind. I guided myself by your example,  I pasted your code an ran some test, but i cant make it work. Nothing seems to trigger the updateTotal. Can i asked you a little bit more of help ? In the value and the label of the input , im using the value of the id of the product to send it via post to the controller.

Comment: Hi @JoaquínSabaté Do you have any error in your Javascript console, when clicking on a checkbox? (F12, then _Console_ tab in Google Chrome). If you do, what does it say? If not, could you update your question by adding the actual HTML which is rendered (not the _jsp_ template)?

Comment: i update the post with the html. I didn´t notice the error on the console. 
El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'from' wich in english is The object does not accept the property or the 'from' method. Iguess the error is for "Array.from"

Comment: Ok, I switched `Array.from` to `[].slice.call`, which should work in most browsers. Can you try that?

Comment: Thanks @blex, i was stuck in here for two days ! that solve my problem it dindn´t brake my controller integration.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The checked flag is either on or off. It doesn't take an argument. So it looks like

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="name" checked> checked </input>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name"> unchecked</input>
```

In your code you'll need something like: ${prdcts.idProducto ? "checked" : ""}

Comment: An `input` is always self-closing

Comment: OK, that code is non-conformant HTML. I added it for demo purposes.

The point is that he needs to put the "checked" attribute in the input clause.